# When would it be more effective to use if/else combinations rather than elif?

Tags: python

In Learn Python the Hard Way, one of the student questions asks:

> **Can you replace elif with a sequence of if-else combinations?**
>
> You can in some situations, but it depends on how each if/else is written. It also means that Python will check every if-else combination, rather than just the first false ones like it would with if-elif-else.

When he says "in some situations," I was just wondering when it would be more effective to use those sequences to replace an elif.

EDIT: Is there any difference between how these two pieces of code will be executed?

```
print "You enter a dark room with two doors.  Do you go through door #1 or door @2?"

door = raw_input("> ")

if door == "1":
    print "Hello."
        # More if/else here
        # ...
        # ...

if door == "2":
    print "Hello again."
        # More if/else here
        # ...
        # ...

else:
    print "End."
```

> 

```
print "You enter a dark room with two doors.  Do you go through door #1 or door @2?"

door = raw_input("> ")

if door == "1":
    print "Hello."
        # More if/else here
        # ...
        # ...

elif door == "2":
    print "Hello again."
        # More if/else here
        # ...
        # ...

else:
    print "End."
```

Comment: if's are always evaluated where elif's are only evaluated if the previous statement evaluates to False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One situation in which a series of `if` statements can be substituted for an `if`...`elif`...`else` block is when each `if` statement contains a `return`:

```
def check(something):
    if something == 1:
        return "foo"
    if something == 2:
        return "bar"
    return "n/a"
```

In that case, the `return` means that by the time the second `if` is reached, you *know* that the first condition was false, so any `else` or `elif` is redundant. Also, in that particular case, if you need to reorder the `if` statements, it's marginally easier because you don't have to worry about an `elif` clause ending up before the `if` clause, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

An odd use, since python doesn't technically have an explicit switch statement, is to use a combination of ifs as a pseudo-switch with fallthrough.

I wouldn't technically recommend this normally, as it's kind of hard to debug and maintain, and not very pythonic, but it's an option where normal if/elif wouldn't be appropriate.

```
def do_something(x):
    y = ""
    if x == 1:
        y += "This and " 
    if x == 1 or x == 2:
        y += "That"
    if x == 3:
        y += "The Other"
    return y
```

**EDIT:**

As for your code supplied, the main difference is in the logic that is created.  A series of ifs will each be set to be evaluable so you may run into issues where you mung variables in ways that you're not expecting.

The if/elif will only evaluate until it hits a valid statement or the final else.

So the short answer would be that you *MAY* want a series of ifs instead of if/elifs if you're dealing with multiple triggers affecting multiple variables, when emulating a switch with fallthrough, or if it's short return statements on a per-if basis.  Most of the time though an if/elif will be more correct and more efficient.

Also, on a compilation end, the compiler will *probably* be able to better handle branch prediction with if/elifs than a series of ifs.